# Jquery .on('click') strange behavior - selects all elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add the text contained inside an `<li>` element when the user clicks on it to an input field `#private_users`. The problem is that if the list looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="user_li_selection">Jane</li>
<li class="user_li_selection">John</li>
<ul>
```

And then the user clicks on 'John', the string that gets puts into the input box looks like `John, Jane, John`. Then, after this first selection, the script behaves normally attaching only the selected names. Basically, it seems like the script is attaching the text contained in all of the li elements and then attaching the text of the one selected. I cant't figure why this is happening. It may be useful to note, that the `<li>` elements are being attached dynamically with a different script.

```
$(document).on('click', '.user_li_selection', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault; 
             var selection = $(this).html();
             var current_string = $('#private_users').val();

             arr = current_string.split(','), i;
             length =  arr.length;

             if (length != 1) {
             arr[length-1] = ' '+selection+', ';
             } else {
             arr[length-1] =  selection+', ';
             }

             $('#private_users').val(arr);

             //$('.input_auto_complete').remove();

          });



     $('#private_users').keyup(function() {

        var input = $(this).val();

        arr = input.split(', '), i; 
        length =  arr.length;
        var current_input = arr[length-1];

        var input_box = $('#private_users');
        var position = input_box.position();

        if ($('.input_auto_complete').length == 0 && input !== '') {
            $('body').append('<div class="input_auto_complete"></div>');
        }

        if (input == '') {
            $('.input_auto_complete').remove();
        }

        $('.input_auto_complete').css('top',position.top + 24);
        $('.input_auto_complete').css('left',position.left);
        $('.input_auto_complete').show();

        $.post('/username-query', {
        'user_input': current_input
        }, function(data) {
        $('.input_auto_complete').empty().append(data);
        }); 

     });

     $('#private_users').blur(function () {

        if ( !$('.user_li_selection').click() ) {
         $('.input_auto_complete').remove();
        }

     });
```

The input field I am targeting is just a simple text input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="private_users" />
```

[**JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE:**](http://jsfiddle.net/JtGdv/1/) (MAKE SURE to SELECT THE INPUT FIELD before selecting an item from the list or the problem will not occur.)

Comment: What is the `i` in `arr = current_string.split(','), i;`? It seems to work fine if I fix this line: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/WCefH/ (although there are better ways to build the string).

Comment: you are trying to do this? http://jsfiddle.net/gjqek/

Comment: Oops, thats from part of the script I removed earlier. Its extraneous.

Comment: @OswaldoAcauan - yes that is it percisely

Comment: Ok, apart from the `i` thing, nothing is wrong and it seems to behave as expected. The error must lie somewhere else if this does not work for you.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok, I'll try adding the rest of the script from this thing but it may be a little messy. Just a sec.

Comment: The rest of the script does not seem to have anything to do with the list so, so it should not have any influence on it... is this really the markup you have? Could it be that you have nested `.user_li_selection` elements?

Comment: Thats what I thought but the html structure looks fine. All of the <li> elements have closing tags.

Comment: Can you replicate the behaviour with a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ That would make it easier to analyse. One problem could be that `arr` and `length` are global. Make them local.

Comment: How are they global? I created them inside the function, shouldn't that make them local?

Comment: You need to use `var` to make them local. Have a look at this more concise version: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/WCefH/3/, maybe it helps. If it does, I will post it as answer.

Comment: That seems to break the script, the auto-suggest box no longer shows up. The Server-side script that I am querying with $.post() simply returns a list of matched items, if that helps.

Comment: @FelixKling Just added JS fiddle example with the weird behavior

Comment: This works fine for me. If I select `private` and then select `john`, it only adds `john` to the list. Tested in Chrome 19.

Comment: @FelixKling AH-HA! Click on the input field first so that it is focused (with the blue line around it...) and then select an item from the drop drown. this should cause the problem to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is this line:

```
if ( !$('.user_li_selection').click() )
```

when the text box looses its focus, you simulate a click on all list elements.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this line, the if statement does not really make sense.

Comment: I was trying to hide the auto-suggest box anytime the input field looses focus.

Comment: Then I guess you can simply remove the `if` statement. `.click` will return a jQuery object, so this expression is always `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text of the clicked `li` with `e.target`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".user_li_selection").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(e.target).text();
    $("#private_users").val(text);
  });
});
```

Comment: The `.user_li_selection` elements are added dynamically, that's why the OP is using event delegation. His script is actually correct. Inside the event handler `this` always refers to the clicked element, so there is no need to use `e.target`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/5V6PP/

```
$(document).on('click', '.user_li_selection', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var selection = $(this).html();
    var current_string = $('#private_users').val();

    arr = current_string.split(',');
    i = 0;
    length =  arr.length;

    if (length != 1) {
        arr[length-1] = ' ' + selection + ', ';
    } else {
        arr[length-1] = selection + ', ';
    }

    $('#private_users').val(arr);

    //$('.input_auto_complete').remove();

});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked. I think @FelixKling is correct in that the problem may lay in some other part of the script. I have added the rest to my original post.

Comment: Didn't work - same issue, behaves differently than the JSFiddle example.

Comment: it still works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/5V6PP/1/  just copy the JS from the JSFiddle and paste into your page

Comment: Copy & paste breaks the script - the auto-suggest box no longer appears.